# can sizzle return elements that do not have any attributes?

Tags: attributes, sizzle

I am experimenting with using a sizzle query to extract elements with out attributes from a webpage.

I can easily return an element by specifying its attribute. 
Ex: doc.Tables.Filter(Find.BySelector("[ID='abc']")) returns elements with ID='abc'

Is there a way to return all the elements that do not have any attributes at all? 
This is what Im shooting for:
**doc.Tables.Filter(Find.BySelector("[]")) 'return all element with no attributes**
Thanks
Ken